# Add element on array

Tags: php, class, constructor

I'm developing a graph data structure, but I'm with a problem:

```
<?php  
class Graph
{
    var $graph_arr = array();

    function Graph()
    {
        $this->graph_arr = array();
        //initialization of nodes, mythical for now
        $n = new Node("A", array("B", "C"));
        $this->graph_arr[] = $n;
        $n = new Node("B", array("A", "D"));
        $this->graph_arr[] = $n;
        $n = new Node("C", array("A", "E", "F"));
        $this->graph_arr[] =$n; 
        $n = new Node("D", array("B"));
        $this->graph_arr[] = $n;
        $n = new Node("E", array("C"));
        $this->graph_arr[] = $n;    
        $n = new Node("F", array("C"));
        $this->graph_arr[] = $n;
    }
};

class Node
{
    var $node_name;
    var $adjacent_nodes;
    var $is_visited;

    function Node($node_name, $adjacent_nodes)
    {
        $this->node_name = $node_name;
        $this->adjacent_nodes = $adjacent_nodes;
    }
    /** returns array of adjacent nodes **/

    function getAdjacentNodes()
    {
        return $this->adjacent_nodes;
    }

    function getNodeName()
    {
        return $this->node_name;
    }

    function isVisited()
    {
        return $this->is_visited;
    }

    function setVisited()
    {
        $this->is_visited = true;
    }
};

?>
```

Well when I create the Graph object, the size of the array is 0. And I can't add new Nodes.

Comment: Maybe you need to construct the class like in this manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: change var to public or private, var is considered in old PHP like version 4

Comment: which array's size is getting zero, and how are you accessing it.

Comment: In PHP constructors are added with __construct

Comment: I was solved the problem. I'm acessing to the array wrong. Now I'm doing it right. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change your Graph class like this:

```
class Graph
{
  var $graph_arr = array();

  function __construct() {
     $this->graph_arr = array();

   //initialization of nodes, mythical for now
   $n = new Node("A", array("B", "C"));
   $this->graph_arr[] = $n;
   $n = new Node("B", array("A", "D"));
   $this->graph_arr[] = $n;
   $n = new Node("C", array("A", "E", "F"));
   $this->graph_arr[] =$n; 
   $n = new Node("D", array("B"));
   $this->graph_arr[] = $n;
   $n = new Node("E", array("C"));
   $this->graph_arr[] = $n;    
   $n = new Node("F", array("C"));
   $this->graph_arr[] = $n;   
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you choose my answer as the answer? :D